# How to open the command terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I know in Linux you have the LX terminal to install an unpack things. Is something like that included in Ubuntu? I an new to Ubuntu and I would like to learn how use it more efficiently.

Comment: You can open a terminal emulator with Control+Alt+T on an Ubuntu default install.

Comment: Hit the Windows key on your keyboard, and type in Terminal.  Click on Terminal.  Boom, you're there.